# How to fix broken DV file using tools available for Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a DV capture which for some reason is broken. By broken I mean that avconv/ffmpeg/avidemux won't open it, although totem and VLC will open it.

I suppose there's something corrupt/wrong at the start of the file.

I need to use avconv/ffmpeg on the file. Currently it says:

```
[dv @ 0x124e680] Can't determine profile of DV input stream.
```

The capture was done from the same device as another file, i.e. the following info from another file is probably the info that's corrupt/missing in the broken one:

```
Input #0, dv, from 'capture004.dv':
  Metadata:
    timecode        : 00:00:02:16
  Duration: 01:00:44.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28800 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo, yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 
                 28800 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1024 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1024 kb/s
```

Is there any way I can fix the broken one?

Comment: If ffmpeg does not play it when VLC can, filing a bug report similar to [this one](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/217?cversion=0&cnum_hist=3) would be good.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3341

Comment: I left you a comment on how to improve your bug report. Please remember to always include your full command line when asking for help with a command or file—also here on Super User. Truncating doesn't achieve much and requires others ask you for build details or ffmpeg version information.

Comment: Ah, yep, later version of ffmpeg will open it. Must have been a bug. I was previously using the latest version available from ppa at https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg

Comment: Glad it worked out. I left an answer so this can be closed—please mark it as accepted. I guess you can close the bug report yourself or delete it. If an FFmpeg developer sees it they will probably just close it as not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jon Severinsson's Ubuntu PPA versions](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg) of ffmpeg are not the latest ones and are still stuck at the 0.x branch.

Download a [recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [compile a new version yourself](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide). Development is very active, and chances are these kinds of bugs are already fixed.